# Mongodb $slice operator with Mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

My Document is as below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b246aae4b0ad1d6b6a5c02"),        
    "name" : "PATHOLOGY",     
    "status" : true,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "updateBy" : "53bcc05a48d1665cd8692993",            
            "date" : ISODate("2014-12-20T10:19:07.246Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to maintain last 5 histories in `history` key :

so i can write following query for that:

```
db.collection.update( 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("53b246aae4b0ad1d6b6a5c02") },
    { $push : { 
        history : 
            {
              $each : [ 
                     {
                        "updateBy" : "53bcc05a48d1665cd8692993",                      
                        "date" : new Date()
                     }
                ] , 
              $slice : -5 
            }
        } 
    } 
);
```

But i don't know how to write `update` query in `MongoTemplate` with `$slice`, `$each` and `$push`.

Comment: `$slice` is not yet supported with `Update` in spring-data-mongodb. Please vote for [DATAMONGO-832](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-832).

Answer (score 0):

As [@ChristophStrobl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422818/christoph-strobl) pointed out in their comment

> `$slice` is not yet supported with Update in spring-data-mongodb. Please
>   vote for [DATAMONGO-832](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-832)

You would need to devise a workaround that utilises the mongoTemplate's **[`executeCommand`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#executeCommand-java.lang.String-)** method, providing the json string with the **[`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)** command:

```
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void pushHistory(String objectId, String userId) {
        Date now = new Date();
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("id", objectId);
        DBObject modifiedObject = new BasicDBObject();
        List<DBObject> eachObjectList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();

        DBObject object = new BasicDBObject().append("updateBy", userId);
        object.append("date", now);
        eachObjectList.add(object);

        modifiedObject.put("$push", 
            new BasicDBObject().append("history", 
                    new BasicDBObject().append("$each", eachObjectList)
                ).append("$slice", -3)
            );

        String json = "{ findAndModify: \"collectionName\", query: " + searchQuery.toString() + ", update: " + modifiedObject.toString();

        try {
            mongoTemplate.executeCommand(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm already doing same using 
`Update update = new Update();
update.push("history", new BasicDBObject("$each", list).append("$slice", -5)); `

Comment: I just want to know is there any in-built support for `$slice` in `spring-data`

Comment: @HarshPatel Unfortunately no. To get this support added in later releases, you might want to vote this up [**here**](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-832).